# Setting Font Colour of a Link to Variable with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set the font colour of a link to the value of a specific variable inline? I can set it to a specific colour as below.

`<%= link_to "Click for more information", info_url(@site), style: 'color: #cc0000;' , class: 'button' %>`

What would be the syntax to insert a variable into the color selector? I didn't expect the code below to work but that is the essence of what I want to do.

`<%= link_to "Click for more information", info_url(@site), style: 'color: @site.colour' , class: 'button' %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is string interpolation
http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

ie:

```
<%= link_to "Click for more information", info_url(@site), style: "color: #{@site.colour}" , class: 'button' %>
```

Comment: Ah, tried that before but I was using single quotes. Thanks!